# Recursive call doesn't return?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search

I implemented a binary search into my program, but for some reason, it completely ignores one of my return statements. The return statement in question is as follows:`return array[mid];`

When I use Eclipse's debugger, I can watch it enter the if statement, run the return, and then it skips to the following two lines: `binarySearch(array, key, low, mid - 1);`, `return null;`.

Any idea as to why that might be happening?

```
public Entry<K, V> binarySearch(Entry<K,V>[] array, K key, int low, int high) {
    if(low >= high) {
        Entry<K,V> notFound = new EntryNode<K,V>(null, null);
        return notFound;
    } else {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if(key.equals(array[mid].getKey()))
            return array[mid];
        else if(comparator.compare(key, array[mid].getKey()) < 0)
            binarySearch(array, key, low, mid - 1);
        else
            binarySearch(array, key, mid + 1, high);
    }   //End else statement
    return null;
}   //End binarySearch method
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in a short but complete console app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `return binarySearch(..)` in both places, otherwise it will fall through and return null.

You should be able to remove the `return null` statement without the compiler telling you the that function does not always return a value.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you forgot to return the result of the inner binarySearch calls. You thus have

```
binarySearch
    binarySearch
        binarySearch
            return array[mid]
        return null
    return null
```